# `ng-click` not working inside `ng-repeat`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to display a multiple button which fires same function but with different parameters but it's `ng-click` function is not working.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="editPhone in studentDetail ">

            <table class="table table-striped m-b-none">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Signup Number</td>
                  <td><input type="text" ng-model="editPhone.phone_no"></td>
                  <td> 
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-addon" ng-click="testJs(editPhone.studentid,'signup',editPhone.phone_no)">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save 
                      </button>
                      <i id="signup" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hide"></i>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Permanent</td>
                  <td><input type="text" ng-model="editPhone.per_tel"></td>
                  <td> 
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-addon" ng-click="saveContactNumbers(editPhone.studentid,'permanent',editPhone.per_tel)">
                          <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
                      </button>
                      <i id="permanent" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hide"></i>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Communication</td>
                  <td><input type="text" ng-model="editPhone.comm_mobileno"></td>
                    <td> 
                      <button class="btn btn-sm  btn-success btn-addon" ng-click="saveContactNumbers(editPhone.studentid,'communication',editPhone.comm_mobileno)">
                         <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
                      </button>
                        <i id="communication" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hide"></i>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Prefered</td>
                  <td><input type="text" ng-model="editPhone.phone_preffered"></td>
                  <td> 

                      <button class="btn btn-sm  btn-success btn-addon" ng-click="saveContactNumbers(editPhone.studentid,'preferred',editPhone.phone_preffered)">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
                      </button>
                        <i id="preferred" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner hide"></i>
                  </td>

                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>


          </div>
```

All my data bound with `studentDetail` are displaying correctly. That means Angular is running well.

Why then is `ng-click` not firing a function?

Here is my function:

```
$scope.saveContactNumbers=function(studentid,typeChange,updatedNumber){
    console.log('saveContactNumbers');
}
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/anujay0402/bw8v770s/) is my full HTML and JS CONTROLLER CODE

Modified::
In my whole code I am unable to fire any controller's function on `ng-click`.

**SOLUTION:: IT WAS TOTALLY MY FAULT. Mistakenly I HAD DEFINED MY FUNCTION BEFORE SOME OTHER FUNCTION ENDS.**

Comment: There is no any visible error in your code.

Comment: yes i believe same but,still my ng-if ,ng-click not working where its coded

Comment: looks like your markup is correct(http://jsfiddle.net/1qtxje0c/1/), show your controller code

Comment: once again check do you have properly added ng-app and ng-controller..

Comment: this is my fiddle where i pasted controller for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/anujay0402/st1yxbke/6/

Comment: @ved yes,if i wouldn't then i believe i wont be getting the values in my text boxes

Comment: I will suggest you to post your full HTML page.

Comment: i have updated my question with full code on fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/st1yxbke/7/, missing ng-app, missing ng-controller, typo instead of "saveContactNumbers()" you have "studentSheet.saveContactNumbers()"; The order of your script is very important;

Comment: ng-controller is defined in my Route and App is called in main HTML file in where i can loading my templates.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope. You have to reference your save method differently:

```
 <body ng-controller="MyPageCtrl as pageCtrl">
   <div class="row" ng-repeat="editPhone in studentDetail ">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-addon" ng-click="pageCtrl.saveContactNumbers(editPhone.studentid,'permanent',editPhone.per_tel)"></button>
   <div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
   (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MyPageCtrl', MyPageCtrl);

    MyPageCtrl.$inject = ['$window'];

    function MyPageCtrl($window) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;

        vm.saveContactNumbers = function (studentId, type, telephone) {
        //save student details
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: it still not working, again i am updating my question with my updated code.

Comment: no error,i dont even get any error if i replace my saveContactNumbers function with any undefined function name

Answer (score 0):

Please pass parameter as a string

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-addon" ng-click="saveContactNumbers('editPhone.studentid','permanent','editPhone.per_tel')">
```

Comment: not working,now i believe there would be a tiny mistake that i am doing,i am sharing my codes